# Hive: SELECT AS and GROUP BY

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a Hive Query like

```
SELECT Year, Month, Day, Hours, Minutes,
           cast((cast(Seconds as int)/15) as int)*15
AS secondMod, Count(*) AS PerCount FROM LoggerTable 
 GROUP BY Year, Month, Day, Hours, Minutes, secondMod 
ORDER BY PerCount;
```

the above query fails with an error

> FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: line 1:175 Invalid Table Alias or Column Reference secondMod

'LoggerTable' is a Hive Table with all columns of string type.

Any workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Year, Month, Day, Hours, Minutes, 
cast((cast(Seconds as int)/15) as int)*15 
AS secondMod, Count(*) AS PerCount FROM LoggerTable 
 GROUP BY Year, Month, Day, Hours, Minutes, 
   cast((cast(Seconds as int)/15) as int)*15
ORDER BY PerCount;
```

Comment: This is a huge pain if you want to define a very complicated `SELECT` and want to use it in your `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`. There is somewhat of a workaround here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028767/why-cant-hive-recognize-alias-named-in-select-part

Answer (score 4):

In Hive 0.11.0 and later, columns can be specified by position if `hive.groupby.orderby.position.alias` is set to `true`.
Please confirm if the following query works for you.

```
SET hive.groupby.orderby.position.alias=true;
SELECT Year
       ,Month
       ,Day
       ,Hours
       ,Minutes
       ,cast((cast(Seconds as int)/15) as int)*15 AS secondMod
       ,count(*) AS PerCount 
FROM LoggerTable 
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
ORDER BY 7;
```

Comment: I tried this, but it would work only for the group by. The query fails when I try order by. Do you have any thoughts why it could happen?
My query looks like this: 
`SET hive.groupby.orderby.position.alias=true;
    SELECT  device ,COUNT ( DISTINCT from_user  ) AS users_sharing
    FROM <db>.<table> GROUP BY 1 order by 2 desc limit 10`
And I got the following error:
`FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 4:21 Invalid table alias or column reference 'from_user': (possible column names are: device, users_sharing)`

Comment: Sorry for the format. I couldn't figure out how to post the query with the indentation preserved.

Comment: Confirm that your `from_user` table alias or column reference exists. Maybe different spelling, typo. A possible solution is to break down your query into two parts:
`hive.groupby.orderby.position.alias=true;
SELECT res.device, res.users_sharing  
FROM (SELECT device, COUNT ( DISTINCT from_user ) AS users_sharing 
   FROM <db>.<table> 
   GROUP BY 1 
   limit  10;
   ) AS res
ORDER BY res.users_sharing`
Let us know how you solve your problem!

Comment: There is no typo in the col name. I tried your suggestion of separating the group by in a subquery and worked!!
So there is a workaround, but I am wondering why the initial query wouldn't work with both group by and order by side-by-side.

Comment: Can you try your original query with `order by 3` and let us know what the results are?

Comment: It has failed with the error saying position 3 doesn't exist: `FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10221]: Invalid position alias in Order By
Position alias: 3 does not exist
The Select List is indexed from 1 to 2`
Is it actually possible in hive to use both group by and order by with positions in the same subquery?

Comment: It seems that Hive does not allow aggregation function in ORDER BY. You could try using your original query substituting `ORDER BY 2` with `ORDER BY users_sharing`