# Why can't hive recognize alias named in select part?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql

Here's the scenario: When I invoke hql as follows, it tells me that it cannot find alias for u1.

```
hive> select user as u1, url as u2 from rank_test where u1 != "";
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:50 Invalid table alias or column reference 'u1': (possible column names are: user, url)
```

This problem is the same as when I try to use `count(*) as cnt`. Could anyone give me some hint on how to use alias in where clause? Thanks a lot!

```
hive> select user, count(*) as cnt from rank_test where cnt >= 2 group by user;
FAILED: ParseException line 1:58 missing EOF at 'where' near 'user'
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `where` clause is evaluated before the `select` clause, which is why you can't refer to select aliases in your where clause.

You can however refer to aliases from a derived table.

```
select * from (
  select user as u1, url as u2 from rank_test
) t1 where u1 <> "";

select * from (
  select user, count(*) as cnt from rank_test group by user
) t1 where cnt >= 2;
```

Side note: a more efficient way to write the last query would be

```
select user, count(*) as cnt from rank_test group by user
having count(*) >= 2
```

If I remember correctly, you can refer to the alias in `having` i.e. `having cnt >= 2`

Comment: Awesome stuff Fuzzy Tree

Comment: Indeed, it's not usually the case, but with Hive you can reference an alias in `having`.

Answer (score 9):

I was able to use Alias in my Hive select statement using backtick symbol ``.

```
SELECT COL_01 AS `Column_A`;
```

The above solution worked for Hive version 1.2.1.

[reference link](https://vcfvct.wordpress.com/2016/01/06/hive-query-select-as-alias-and-format-date/)

Comment: ```SELECT COL_01 AS `Column_A` where Column_A = "Test"```; may not work.