# Hive Query issue - Invalid table alias or column reference

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I have a query which contains Case statement and the output of the CASE is used to compare another column in Hive.I am not able to run the same query.Here is the query.

```
    SELECT
          AL1.RECORD_ID,
          AL1.CARRIER_CODE,
          AL1.ORIG_AP_CTY_CDE,
          AL1.ORIG_STATE_CODE,
          AL1.ORIG_COUNTRY_CODE,
          AL1.ORIG_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER,
          CASE
              WHEN AL1.ORIG_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER > 99 THEN CONCAT(CAST(AL1.ORIG_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER/10  AS INT), '0')
              WHEN AL1.ORIG_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER IN ('1','2','4','6','7','8','9') THEN '000'
              ELSE AL1.ORIG_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER
          END AS ALL_ORIG_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE,
          AL1.ORIG_WORLD_AREA_NUMBER,
          AL1.DEST_AP_CTY_CDE,
          AL1.DEST_STATE_CODE,
          AL1.DEST_COUNTRY_CODE,
          AL1.DEST_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER,
          CASE
               WHEN AL1.DEST_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER > 99 THEN CONCAT(CAST(AL1.DEST_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER/10 AS INT), '0')
               WHEN AL1.DEST_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER IN ('1','2','4','6','7','8','9') THEN '000'
               ELSE AL1.DEST_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER
          END AS ALL_DEST_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE,
          AL1.DEST_WORLD_AREA_NUMBER,
          AL1.FRBS_CDE,
          AL1.OW_RT_CDE,
          AL1.PUB_RULE_TRF_NUM,
          AL1.FARE_RULE_NUM,
          AL1.PUB_RTG_NUM,
          AL1.PUB_FTNTE_ID_CDE,
          AL1.FARE_TYPE_CODE,
          AL1.SEASON_TYPE_CODE,
          AL1.DAY_OF_WEEK_TYPE_CODE,
          AL2.CATEGORY_CONTROL_ID,
          AL2.CATEGORY_NUMBER  AS GROUP_CATEGORY_NUMBER,
          AL2.SEQUENCE_NUMBER,
          AL2.LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE,
          AL2.LOCATION1_CODE,
          AL2.LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE,
          AL2.LOCATION2_CODE,
          AL2.FARE_CLASS_CODE,
          AL2.GENERAL_RULE_TARIFF_NUMBER,
          AL2.GENERAL_RULE_NUMBER,
          AL2.GENERAL_RULE_IND,
          'F' AS REC_IND
    FROM TMP_TD_CNSTR_WINNING_FARES  AL1
    INNER JOIN TMP_TD_CNSTRPOST_CAT_CONTROL_ONLY_LIMITED_F AL2
    ON (
        AL1.CARRIER_CODE=AL2.CARRIER_CODE
        AND AL1.PUB_RULE_TRF_NUM=AL2.TARIFF_NUMBER
        AND AL1.FARE_RULE_NUM = AL2.RULE_FOOTNOTE_CODE
        AND AL1.PUB_RTG_NUM = AL2.ROUTING_NUMBER
        AND AL1.SEASON_TYPE_CODE = AL2.SEASON_TYPE_CODE
        AND AL1.PUB_FTNTE_ID_CDE = AL2.FOOTNOTE_CODE
        AND AL1.OW_RT_CDE = AL2.OW_RT_IND
        AND AL1.FARE_TYPE_CODE = AL2.FARE_TYPE_CODE
        AND AL1.DAY_OF_WEEK_TYPE_CODE = AL2. DAY_OF_WEEK_TYPE_CODE
        )
    INNER JOIN TMP_TD_CNSTRPOST_FRBS_MATCH_F AL4
    ON ( AL1.CARRIER_CODE = AL4.CARRIER_CODE
         AND AL1.PUB_RULE_TRF_NUM = AL4.PUB_RULE_TRF_NUM
         AND AL1.FARE_RULE_NUM = AL4.RULE_NUM
         AND AL1.FRBS_CDE = AL4.FRBS_CDE
         AND AL2.FARE_CLASS_CODE = AL4.FARE_CLASS_CODE
        )
    WHERE
     ( (
               (COALESCE(LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE, '')  = '') OR
               (LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE = 'C' AND LOCATION1_CODE = ORIG_AP_CTY_CDE)  OR
               (LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE = 'S' AND LOCATION1_CODE = ORIG_STATE_CODE) OR
               (LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE = 'N' AND LOCATION1_CODE = ORIG_COUNTRY_CODE) OR
               (LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE = 'Z' AND LOCATION1_CODE = ORIG_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER) OR
               (LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE = 'Z' AND LOCATION1_CODE = ALL_ORIG_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE) OR
               (LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE = 'A' AND LOCATION1_CODE = ORIG_WORLD_AREA_NUMBER)
             )
             AND
             (
               (COALESCE(LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE, '')  = '') OR
               (LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE = 'C' AND LOCATION2_CODE = DEST_AP_CTY_CDE)  OR
               (LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE = 'S' AND LOCATION2_CODE = DEST_STATE_CODE) OR
               (LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE = 'N' AND LOCATION2_CODE = DEST_COUNTRY_CODE) OR
               (LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE = 'Z' AND LOCATION2_CODE = DEST_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER) OR
               (LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE = 'Z' AND LOCATION2_CODE = ALL_DEST_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE) OR
               (LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE = 'A' AND LOCATION2_CODE = DEST_WORLD_AREA_NUMBER)
             )
                     )
       OR
            ((
               (COALESCE(LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE, '')  = '') OR
               (LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE = 'C' AND LOCATION1_CODE = DEST_AP_CTY_CDE)  OR
               (LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE = 'S' AND LOCATION1_CODE = DEST_STATE_CODE) OR
               (LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE = 'N' AND LOCATION1_CODE = DEST_COUNTRY_CODE) OR
               (LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE = 'Z' AND LOCATION1_CODE = DEST_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER) OR
               (LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE = 'Z' AND LOCATION1_CODE = ALL_DEST_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE) OR
               (LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE = 'A' AND LOCATION1_CODE = DEST_WORLD_AREA_NUMBER)
             )
             AND
             (
               (COALESCE(LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE, '')  = '') OR
               (LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE = 'C' AND LOCATION2_CODE = ORIG_AP_CTY_CDE)  OR
               (LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE = 'S' AND LOCATION2_CODE = ORIG_STATE_CODE) OR
               (LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE = 'N' AND LOCATION2_CODE = ORIG_COUNTRY_CODE) OR
               (LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE = 'Z' AND LOCATION2_CODE = ORIG_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER) OR
               (LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE = 'Z' AND LOCATION2_CODE = ALL_ORIG_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE) OR
               (LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE = 'A' AND LOCATION2_CODE = ORIG_WORLD_AREA_NUMBER)
             )
     )
    ;
```

The error I am encountering is

FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 72:59 Invalid table alias or column reference 'ALL_ORIG_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE

Please help me resolving the issue.Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

The where clause is evaluated before the select clause, so you can't use ALL_DEST_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE in where clause.
You can try it in a derived table or having clause.

[relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028767/why-cant-hive-recognize-alias-named-in-select-part)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jerrick.It worked for me using derived table.Here is the updated query.

```
            SELECT
                *
              FROM (SELECT
                AL1.RECORD_ID,
                AL1.CARRIER_CODE,
                AL1.ORIG_AP_CTY_CDE,
                AL1.ORIG_STATE_CODE,
                AL1.ORIG_COUNTRY_CODE,
                AL1.ORIG_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER,
                CASE
                  WHEN AL1.ORIG_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER > 99 THEN CONCAT((CAST(AL1.ORIG_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER / 10 AS int)), '0')
                  WHEN AL1.ORIG_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER IN ('1', '2', '4', '6', '7', '8', '9') THEN '000'
                  ELSE AL1.ORIG_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER
                END AS ALL_ORIG_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE,
                AL1.ORIG_WORLD_AREA_NUMBER,
                AL1.DEST_AP_CTY_CDE,
                AL1.DEST_STATE_CODE,
                AL1.DEST_COUNTRY_CODE,
                AL1.DEST_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER,
                CASE
                  WHEN AL1.DEST_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER > 99 THEN CONCAT((CAST(AL1.DEST_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER / 10 AS int)), '0')
                  WHEN AL1.DEST_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER IN ('1', '2', '4', '6', '7', '8', '9') THEN '000'
                  ELSE AL1.DEST_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER
                END AS ALL_DEST_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE,
                AL1.DEST_WORLD_AREA_NUMBER,
                AL1.FRBS_CDE,
                AL1.OW_RT_CDE,
                AL1.PUB_RULE_TRF_NUM,
                AL1.FARE_RULE_NUM,
                AL1.PUB_RTG_NUM,
                AL1.PUB_FTNTE_ID_CDE,
                AL1.FARE_TYPE_CODE,
                AL1.SEASON_TYPE_CODE,
                AL1.DAY_OF_WEEK_TYPE_CODE,
                AL2.CATEGORY_CONTROL_ID,
                AL2.CATEGORY_NUMBER AS GROUP_CATEGORY_NUMBER,
                AL2.SEQUENCE_NUMBER,
                AL2.LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE,
                AL2.LOCATION1_CODE,
                AL2.LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE,
                AL2.LOCATION2_CODE,
                AL2.FARE_CLASS_CODE,
                AL2.GENERAL_RULE_TARIFF_NUMBER,
                AL2.GENERAL_RULE_NUMBER,
                AL2.GENERAL_RULE_IND,
                'F' AS REC_IND
              FROM TMP_TD_CNSTR_WINNING_FARES AL1
              INNER JOIN TMP_TD_CNSTRPOST_CAT_CONTROL_ONLY_LIMITED_F AL2
                ON (
                AL1.CARRIER_CODE = AL2.CARRIER_CODE
                AND AL1.PUB_RULE_TRF_NUM = AL2.TARIFF_NUMBER
                AND AL1.FARE_RULE_NUM = AL2.RULE_FOOTNOTE_CODE
                AND AL1.PUB_RTG_NUM = AL2.ROUTING_NUMBER
                AND AL1.SEASON_TYPE_CODE = AL2.SEASON_TYPE_CODE
                AND AL1.PUB_FTNTE_ID_CDE = AL2.FOOTNOTE_CODE
                AND AL1.OW_RT_CDE = AL2.OW_RT_IND
                AND AL1.FARE_TYPE_CODE = AL2.FARE_TYPE_CODE
                AND AL1.DAY_OF_WEEK_TYPE_CODE = AL2.DAY_OF_WEEK_TYPE_CODE
                )
              INNER JOIN TMP_TD_CNSTRPOST_FRBS_MATCH_F AL4
                ON (AL1.CARRIER_CODE = AL4.CARRIER_CODE
                AND AL1.PUB_RULE_TRF_NUM = AL4.PUB_RULE_TRF_NUM
                AND AL1.FARE_RULE_NUM = AL4.RULE_NUM
                AND AL1.FRBS_CDE = AL4.FRBS_CDE
                AND AL2.FARE_CLASS_CODE = AL4.FARE_CLASS_CODE
                )) AS WF
              WHERE ((
              (COALESCE(LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE, '') = '')
              OR (LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE = 'C'
              AND LOCATION1_CODE = ORIG_AP_CTY_CDE)
              OR (LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE = 'S'
              AND LOCATION1_CODE = ORIG_STATE_CODE)
              OR (LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE = 'N'
              AND LOCATION1_CODE = ORIG_COUNTRY_CODE)
              OR (LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE = 'Z'
              AND LOCATION1_CODE = ORIG_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER)
              OR (LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE = 'Z'
              AND LOCATION1_CODE = WF.ALL_ORIG_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE)
              OR (LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE = 'A'
              AND LOCATION1_CODE = ORIG_WORLD_AREA_NUMBER)
              )
              AND (
              (COALESCE(LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE, '') = '')
              OR (LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE = 'C'
              AND LOCATION2_CODE = DEST_AP_CTY_CDE)
              OR (LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE = 'S'
              AND LOCATION2_CODE = DEST_STATE_CODE)
              OR (LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE = 'N'
              AND LOCATION2_CODE = DEST_COUNTRY_CODE)
              OR (LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE = 'Z'
              AND LOCATION2_CODE = DEST_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER)
              OR (LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE = 'Z'
              AND LOCATION2_CODE = WF.ALL_DEST_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE)
              OR (LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE = 'A'
              AND LOCATION2_CODE = DEST_WORLD_AREA_NUMBER)
              )
              )
              OR ((
              (COALESCE(LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE, '') = '')
              OR (LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE = 'C'
              AND LOCATION1_CODE = DEST_AP_CTY_CDE)
              OR (LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE = 'S'
              AND LOCATION1_CODE = DEST_STATE_CODE)
              OR (LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE = 'N'
              AND LOCATION1_CODE = DEST_COUNTRY_CODE)
              OR (LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE = 'Z'
              AND LOCATION1_CODE = DEST_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER)
              OR (LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE = 'Z'
              AND LOCATION1_CODE = WF.ALL_DEST_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE)
              OR (LOCATION1_TYPE_CODE = 'A'
              AND LOCATION1_CODE = DEST_WORLD_AREA_NUMBER)
              )
              AND (
              (COALESCE(LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE, '') = '')
              OR (LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE = 'C'
              AND LOCATION2_CODE = ORIG_AP_CTY_CDE)
              OR (LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE = 'S'
              AND LOCATION2_CODE = ORIG_STATE_CODE)
              OR (LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE = 'N'
              AND LOCATION2_CODE = ORIG_COUNTRY_CODE)
              OR (LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE = 'Z'
              AND LOCATION2_CODE = ORIG_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE_NUMBER)
              OR (LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE = 'Z'
              AND LOCATION2_CODE = WF.ALL_ORIG_GEOGRAPHIC_ZONE)
              OR (LOCATION2_TYPE_CODE = 'A'
              AND LOCATION2_CODE = ORIG_WORLD_AREA_NUMBER)
              )
              )
            ;
```