# Hive: More clean way to SELECT AS and GROUP BY

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I try to write Hive Sql like that

```
SELECT count(1), substr(date, 1, 4) as year
FROM ***
GROUP BY year
```

But Hive cannot recognize the alias name 'year', it complains that:
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:79 Invalid table alias or column reference 'year'

One solution([Hive: SELECT AS and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600049/hive-select-as-and-group-by)) suggest to use 'GROUP BY substr(date, 1, 4)'.

It works!
However in some cases **the value I want to group by may be generated from multiple lines of hive function code**, it's very ugly to write code like

```
SELECT count(1), func1(func2(..........................)) AS something
FROM ***
GROUP BY func1(func2(..........................))
```

Is there any clean way in Hive to do that? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Specifying the position in Group By will solve your issue. This position number in Group By **works even when SET hive.groupby.orderby.position.alias=true;**
(Hive 0.12)

```
SELECT count(1), substr(date, 1, 4) as year  
FROM ***
GROUP BY 2;
```

Comment: Awesome. I was searching for this

Comment: it worked for me, but only when the property is set to true

Answer (score 9):

In Hive 0.11.0 and later, columns can be specified by position if hive.groupby.orderby.position.alias is set to true (the default is false).
So setting `set hive.groupby.orderby.position.alias=true;` in your .hql (or .hiverc for a permanent solution) will do the trick and then you can type `group by 2` for the above example.
Source: [hive language manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+GroupBy)

Answer (score 0):

One solution that comes to mind is put `GROUP BY` to outer query:

```
SELECT count(*) , year FROM 
(
   SELECT substr(date, 1, 4) as year FORM ***
) inner
GROUP BY year
```

GL!

Comment: How about the efficiency? It seems that Hive will first generate a temporary table with the same size, and then make the aggregation operation?

Comment: You are 100% correct it might influence adversely performance. But it seems to only way to omit function use in `Group by`. Question here is if hive evaluates function value twice in your regular query?  My guess is that is evaluating it only one time. In this case your original query seems to be optimal.