# Concat and then group by in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have 3 columns in a table as given below:

```
|---------------------|------------------|-------------|
|      dept           |     class        |    item     |
|---------------------|------------------|-------------|
|          234        |         34       |      6783   |
|---------------------|------------------|-------------|
|          784        |         78       |      2346   |
|---------------------|------------------|-------------|
```

while I'm concatenating 3 columns and creating a column as 'item_no' (value  234-34-6783), 
it throws an error when I'm using the new column item_no in group by function - 'Invalid table alias or column reference'
Could someone help me with this?

```
select dept, class, item, concat(dept, '-', class, '-', item) as item_no, sum(sales)
from sales_table
group by dept, class, item, item_no;
```

column data types are smallint

Comment: Show us your query attempt.

Comment: Column data types?

Comment: select dept, class, item, concat(dept, '-', class, '-', item) as item_no, sum(sales) from sales_table
group by dept, class, item, item_no;

Comment: column data types are smallint

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29443253/hive-more-clean-way-to-select-as-and-group-by if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two methods:

```
select concat(dept, '-', class, '-', item) as item_no, count(*)
from t
group by concat(dept, '-', class, '-', item) ;
```

Or:

```
select concat(dept, '-', class, '-', item) as item_no, count(*)
from t
group by dept, class, item ;
```

That said, I thought Hive supported aliases in `group by`, so this should also work:

```
select concat(dept, '-', class, '-', item) as item_no, count(*)
from t
group by item_no ;
```

This would not work if `item_no` were a column in the table, though.  And positional notation also works:

```
select concat(dept, '-', class, '-', item) as item_no, count(*)
from t
group by 1 ;
```